# Every Object in Stack gets null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, stack, gameobject

I wan't to read every child from a Gameobject on click to a Stack.
After that i want to destroy all these objects, so they aren't shown.

In my plan, these objects should still be available in the stack.
But if i want to add the objects from the stack again, they are all null.

I'm new to Unity and have no clue why this shouldn't work.

I'm sorry if this question was asked before, but i haven't seen any similar questions.

```
else if(!stacked)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < parent.transform.childCount; i++)
            {
                aufgenommeneKarten.Push(parent.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject);
                Destroy(parent.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject);
            }
            stacked = !stacked;
        }
        else
        {
            if (aufgenommeneKarten.Count != 0)
            {
                go = new GameObject();
                go = aufgenommeneKarten.Pop();
                go.transform.SetParent(parent.transform, false); 
            }
            else
            {
                stacked = !stacked;
            }
        }
```

This is my code.

Comment: why are you destroying? will it not be garbage collected?

Comment: Can you show the `Destroy` method?

Comment: The Destroy Method is the normal Method from Unity, i didn't change anything there. 


    public static void Destroy(Object obj)
    {
      float t = 0.0f;
      Object.Destroy(obj, t);
    }

The Objects get Destroyed after the for-loop is finished and after that, the stack is filled with null-Values

Comment: So, have you tried not destroying it?

Comment: I tried and like this the Stack is still full, thanks. 

But like this, the objects are obviously not destroyed. So is there a possibility to clone the Gameobject and Push this to the array?

Comment: I think you're missing the point.Unless you create a real clone: there is only one. If you destroy it, you destroy it. You can clone it, but why? It will be hard to deep copy the whole state and it lead to poor performance. So, if you don't want to show it, use an alternative besides destroying it ;-)

Comment: Okay, thank you, i finally understood.
I know change the activeState and reactivate it, if i need it.

  parent.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.SetActive(false);

Comment: Cool :-) ... enjoy :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't tink you're working with actual deep copies of the object.

So here:

```
aufgenommeneKarten.Push(parent.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject);
Destroy(parent.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject); // this will act on the pushed object
```

The pushed `parent.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject` is being `Destroy`ed afterward. I do not know how your Destroy method is implemented, but I recon if you Dispose/destroy etc it, you'll actually refering to the same piece of memory. So, Destroying one, will destroy the pushed one as well.

---

On top of that:
you do nothing to validate: `parent.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject` when you're pushing it. Are you sure it's not `null` there?

---

Also, `stacked = !stacked;`: your logic implies this can be set explicit. Like `stacked = true`. In your case: I would advise it to prevent potential bugs.

---

This part:

```
go = new GameObject();
go = aufgenommeneKarten.Pop();
```

seems to use a field `go`: that can be a bit tricky in several scenarios. I recon it's best to skip the first line:

```
//go = new GameObject();  not needed
go = aufgenommeneKarten.Pop();
```

Comment: Okay, thank you.
The items get destroyed afterwards, if i debug before destroying there are values on the stack.
The go is a GameObject, i wasn't sure if i need the first line. 

Is there a possibility to copy it to a new memory, so it doesn't get destroyed?

Comment: *"The items get destroyed afterwards, if i debug before destroying there are values on the stack"*... what I mean is this that your destroy method will act on the pushed object as well - which might cause unexpected behavior. That why I am asking: can you show the destroy function?

Comment: ```
public static void Destroy(Object obj)
    {
      float t = 0.0f;
      Object.Destroy(obj, t);
    }
```
This is the method from Unity